# AES Encryption and decryption using jks file

Tags: aes

I have one small doubt as i am new to AES.

I encrypted a string using one certificate with some password lets say , 'xxx'.

Now i duplicated the certificate by changing the password of it.

When i try to decrypt the encrypted string with the duplicated cert, it says Bad padding exception.Exception in thread "main" javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded

However, when i use the original cert, it decrypts properly.

Could anyone please guide me on it?

```
public SecretKey retrieveKey(String password, byte[] certFile) throws Exception {
        try {
            String alias = null;
            certPass = password;
            char[] pass = certPass.toCharArray();
            KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance("jceks");
            InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(certFile);
            keyStore.load(inputStream, pass);
            Enumeration enumeration = keyStore.aliases();

            while (enumeration.hasMoreElements()) {
                alias = (String) enumeration.nextElement();
            }

            Certificate cert = keyStore.getCertificate(alias);

            Key key = cert.getPublicKey();
            aesSecretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getEncoded(), algorithm);
            byte[] encoded = aesSecretKey.getEncoded();
            byte[] encryptionKey = Arrays.copyOfRange(encoded, encoded.length - 16, encoded.length);
            aesSecretKey = new SecretKeySpec(encryptionKey, algorithm);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw e;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw e;
        }
        return aesSecretKey;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use RSA to wrap / unwrap the AES key. The public key *is not identical* to the AES key, so the following code is certainly incorrect:

```
Key key = cert.getPublicKey();
aesSecretKey = new SecretKeySpec(key.getEncoded(), algorithm);
```